Can you wire a second light to have constant power from a switch?
I have a ceiling light on a dimmer. A second light is also wired in that is also controlled by the dimmer.  Is there any way for me to convert this second light to constant power for a ceiling fan that isn't controlled by the dimmer switch?

Is the second light fed from the first light or from the switch? Where is the always hot and neutral, the source, at the light or at the switch?

Sure there is. How easy or hard that will be depends on details of the wiring at present, but if the wiring at present does not make it easy you go the hard way and run new cable to it, with whatever drywall repair that may entail depending on details of consruction.  turn off the circuit breaker, open all three boxes (light one, light two, switch) and take pictures that show the present wiring connections (do not disconnect any wires, do pull things out far enough and take clear enough pictures tat we can see the wiring connections and what cables they lead to in pictures. [Edit] those in.

Second light is fed from the first light.  The power source is at the switch
